# CodenameOne UWP app submission to Windows store error

Tags: uwp, codenameone, windows-store

Trying to submit CodenameOne UWP app to Windows store produces the error below:

> Package acceptance validation error: You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages. Please upload the Microsoft Store appxupload file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much says it. You need to submit an appstore build to the appstore. To do that you need to open Codename One Settings, go into the UWP section and select the appropriate target from the combo box there. See https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-uwp.html

Comment: I did that already, I chose "Windows store build" it didn't work, I chose again "Windows store build upload" didn't still work.

Comment: In the resulting bundle did you get an appxupload file?